# Could not find main class while it does exist

Tags: java, classpath, bnd

I've got an issue with running the bnd launcher. The actual problem came up during build using gradle, but it also doesn't work when I call the jar directly. The Launcher class really does exist in that jar and it does have a main method. Anyone know why I got this error?

```
$ java -cp cnf/cache/biz.aQute.launcher/biz.aQute.launcher-1.4.0.jar aQute.launcher.Launcher
Error: Could not find or load main class aQute.launcher.Launcher
```

When I read the content of the jar, I can see that the Launcher class is really there.

```
$ jar tvf cnf/cache/biz.aQute.launcher/biz.aQute.launcher-1.4.0.jar
  1490 Fri Sep 26 06:49:00 CEST 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
       ...
  1586 Fri Sep 26 06:49:00 CEST 2014 aQute/launcher/Launcher$1.class
  2270 Fri Sep 26 06:49:00 CEST 2014 aQute/launcher/Launcher$2.class
   794 Fri Sep 26 06:49:00 CEST 2014 aQute/launcher/Launcher$3.class
  1133 Fri Sep 26 06:49:00 CEST 2014 aQute/launcher/Launcher$4.class
  1100 Fri Sep 26 06:49:00 CEST 2014 aQute/launcher/Launcher$5.class
  1260 Fri Sep 26 06:49:00 CEST 2014 aQute/launcher/Launcher$AllPermissionCollection.class
  1149 Fri Sep 26 06:49:00 CEST 2014 aQute/launcher/Launcher$AllPolicy.class
 37566 Fri Sep 26 06:49:00 CEST 2014 aQute/launcher/Launcher.class
       ...
```

I've also tried loading another random class from another random jar and that does work. Only when the main method is missing, I get a different error (Main method not found in class).

Also the rights on all these files are the same, otherwise I also couldn't run 'jar tvf'.

So, any ideas?

Comment: Does the jar contain all required classes? A class requiring another class that is not found could trigger an error like this.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace.

Comment: There is no stack trace. Only this message. When I add the -verbose option to java, I only see classes being loaded from the rt.jar.

Comment: Also, if it is missing required class (due to some other dependancy), I should see a ClassNotFoundException on NoClassDefFoundError. This message only should come up when it can not find the class file. But it is there! Also, I've tried adding the OSGi dependancies (the only one I can see https://github.com/bndtools/bnd/blob/master/biz.aQute.launcher/src/aQute/launcher/Launcher.java), but that doesn't help.

Comment: Try to see your desired Class inside using JAD Decompiler and check if the main method exists in there or nor ~

Comment: Yes, I've checked it with the Java Decompiler. Also, when it can find the class and there is no main method, it gives a different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems that I was missing a dependency, but it was an OSGi framework. When I added the felix framework to the classpath, it did start. Apparently, the Launcher class implements an interface from the OSGi framework and it won't load the class at all when it can't find this class. This could be an improvement for the java runtime (mainly the verbose output could mention this problem).

Now the question is why bnd tries to start the launcher witout a framework, but this is something I've asked them.

Comment: I had the same problem. Apparently, Bndtools/Bnd still has this same flaw at the beginning of 2019. It would be nice if it were fixed, but it's probably too low a priority.