# Getting "Error: Could not find or load main class aQute.launcher.Launcher" in Eclipse IDE even though it works in command line

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, bndtools

I am currently on a project which uses OSGi/Bndtools. I'm still new to OSGi/Bndtools so please be patient with me.

I had been developing using Eclipse IDE (2020-03) with Bndtools (5.0.1). However, I reformatted my PC and I can't seem to get my OSGi program to work on my new Eclipse IDE/Bndtools setup.
I am currently using Eclipse (2020-03) with Bndtools (5.3.0 REL). (I have not found a way to download the older Bndtools version 5.0.1).

**Summary of error:**
When I click the '**Run OSGi**' button for my BND Run Description file (`stub.bndrun`), I see the following error in the Eclipse console:

`Error: Could not find or load main class aQute.launcher.Launcher`

There is no other text given in console, and the OSGi program fails to run.

However, when I execute the following line in terminal, my OSGi/Bnd program **does indeed run**:

`bnd stub.bndrun`

where `stub.bndrun` is the same BND Run Description file.

**EDIT:** Here's the repo which you can use to reproduce my issue: https://github.com/vorajeem/bndtools_error_reproduce_public.git

Other details of `stub.bndrun` are given below:

```
-runfw: org.apache.felix.framework;version='[5.2.0,5.2.0]'
-runee: JavaSE-1.8
-runsystemcapabilities: ${native_capability}

-resolve.effective: active

-runvm: -Dosgi.console
```

I think my problem is similar to the one given in the following question:[Could not find main class while it does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27457710/could-not-find-main-class-while-it-does-exist).
But I do not understand the answer given to the question in the link above.

**Attempt 1:**
Based on the answer to question #27457710 given above, I have added the Apache Felix framework (5.2.0) to the 'Run Bundles', but I still get the same error message.

I have seen other questions with a similar error message on StackOverflow (i.e. `Could not find or load main class [package-name]`. However, no mention is made of Bndtools - and I think my issue may be related to the way Bndtools is setup on my PC.

**Attempt 2:**
I've added  'biz.aQute.launcher' (3.0.0) to my 'Run Bundles', but I still get the same error message.

Requesting your help. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I've added `-runvm -verbose:class` to `stub.bndrun`, and clicked 'Run OSGi'/'Debug OSGi'. The output is long list of the classes which are loaded (as well as the previous error I had been seeing). I've added the first 2 lines and the last few lines of the output. It seems like it *successfully* loads all the **JAVA** packages (The loaded packages all start with `java.` or `sun.` prefix and they all come from `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib`).

However, it cannot find any **OSGi/Bndtools packages**(??). I'm wondering if my Bndtools repositories are setup correctly?... How can I make sure that is the case?

```
[Opened /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.io.Serializable from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
...
[Loaded java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator$Attribute from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.text.Format$Field from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.text.MessageFormat$Field from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar]
Error: Could not find or load main class aQute.launcher.Launcher
```

Comment: Could you add `-runtrace = true` to the bndrun file and show the output?

Comment: Sorry... I have tried adding the `runtrace: true` as a separate line to the .bndrun file, but I am still getting the same error in the console without any additional output (i.e. `Error: Could not find or load main class aQute.launcher.Launcher`). The console does not show other output line besides that error line given above. I have also tried adding the text `runtrace = true` (verbatim as per your recommendation), but I am still seeing the same output. I wonder if I am putting this `runtrace: true` line in the wrong 'place' in the .bndrun file?

Comment: After adding `runtrace: true` to my .bndrun file I can still run the OSGi program in terminal, but not in Eclipse/bndtools. When I execute the command ```bnd stub.bndrun``` in terminal, my OSGi program runs successfully with a whole lot of added trace lines. I've given some of the output below: `# properties {launch.name=runtime, launch.noreferences=false, launch.trace=true, launch.notificationPort=-1, launch.system.capabilities=osgi.native;osgi.native.osname:List<String>="Linux";osgi.native.osversion:Version=4.15.0.-142-generic;osgi.native.processor:List<String>="x86-64,amd64,em64,` ...

Comment: I've also tried clicking the 'Debug OSGi' icon for my file `stub.bndrun` in Eclipse. This also produces the same single error line.

Comment: You could add `-runvm -verbose:class `. This should show the class loading and might shed some light

Comment: @PeterKriens, thank you... I've added that option to stub.bndrun now. And I've edited my question to show some of this new output (see question above).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I was just trying to start an empty OSGi-Component generated with the bndtools-template.

In my case I just had to remove the generated module-info.java and the bndrun started correctly.

Comment: Removing the module-info.java solved that problem